# VueJS - “npm run build” does not generate index.html file in dist folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack

I have developed a VueJS project. After I run the command
`npm run build`
a dist folder containing a build.js file, build.js.map and images, get generated.
But there is no index.html file in /dist.
My project structure looks like this

And my webpack.config.js looks like this

```
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map',

}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Here is my package.json

```
  "name": "jitsi-demo",
  "description": "This is demo Jitsi Project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "---",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ajax": "0.0.4",
    "jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.11"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.0",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  }
}
```

I have tried using CopyWebpackPlugin and HtmlWebpackPlugin after using I get another error

````
        ^

ReferenceError: HtmlWebpackPlugin is not defined```
````

Comment: You should migrate your project to [Vue CLI 3](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html)

Comment: You should be able to add the [HTML Webpack Plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/). Make sure to install it and import it before referencing it in your Webpack file. Though, like @GabrielWillemann said, if you're starting a new project, Vue CLI is probably going to be easier